# Public class extends internal class

Tags: c#

I have an internal class `A` that does a lot of stuff and I have a set of other classes `B`, `D`, `E` that inherit from class `A`. Of course this won't work as the compiler will complain about a public class not being able to extend an internal one (see [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3626958/c-why-cant-my-public-class-extend-an-internal-class) for an explanation).

I don't want `A` to be public as I don't want my users to inherit from it. I want them to only use `B`, `D`, `E`.

I know I can hide the class from Intellisense using `[EditorBrowsable(EditorBrowsableState.Never)]` but the users can still access it using reflection :(

Is there a way I can achieve this?

Comment: Why are classes `B`, `D` and `E` outside of the assembly `A` is in? This sorta conveys that `B,D,E` are _"users"_ or outsiders if you will. So `A` should probably just be public.

Comment: @gideon It does not matter, they can be either in our out. I just don't want to expose the base class

Comment: You want to allow inheritance from a class to a select few?

Comment: @hometoast Partly yes. I want to only expose a set of known features and I don't want the users to define their own

Comment: @GETah yes it does, an `internal` class is only visible to classes within the assembly, it is NOT visible to classes outside. From your description seems like `B,D,E` are outside the assembly.

Comment: Since your changing the signature of the method, your not inheriting the object anymore. Use the new modifier on the method.

Comment: @gideon Yes, they are outside but the assemblies are friends :)

Comment: @GETah ah well C# doesn't really have the notion of C++'s `friend`

Comment: @GETah: If the assemblies are friends (i.e. marked with the [`InternalsVisibleTo`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.compilerservices.internalsvisibletoattribute.aspx) attribute), you should have no problems accessing internal identifiers.

Comment: @gideon Yes it does :) http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/0tke9fxk(v=vs.80).aspx

Comment: @GETah ah thanks for teaching me something new. You should probably put this detail in your question.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Assuming that `A` is in the assembly *A*, and `B`, `D` and `E` are in the assembly *BDE*, you can declare the [`InternalsVisibleTo` attribute](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.compilerservices.internalsvisibletoattribute.aspx) on *A* to make *BDE* a friend assembly. Like this, `B`, `D` and `E` will be able to see `A`.

Still, you cannot inherit from `A`, as superclasses cannot have a lower visibility than subclasses. You can solve this by declaring `A` *public* while making all of its constructors *internal*. This way, only code with *internal*  access to `A` will be able to derive from `A`.

Comment: @GETah: Note that you can also do fancy things with the `sealed` keyword in this respect. e.g. seal classes `B` and `D`, and do not seal `E` on the class level, but only a few members thereof, to create a subclassable base class for custom classes.