# Protected internal constructor

Tags: c#, inheritance

I have a class `ClassA` that is a base class of other classes. I want this class constructor  to be internal and protected so that it can't be inherited and instantiated from outside of my assembly (I can't make it sealed because I have other internal classes inheriting from it, you can see my other related question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11190765/public-class-extends-internal-class)) so I modified it to be like this:

```
public abstract ClassA{
    internal protected ClassA(){
    }
}
```

I have been told that this won't work as the combination `internal protected` is interpreted as `internal` OR `protected` which apparently makes the constructor only `protected` :( (visible from the outside)

**Questions**

1. If that is true, why is `internal protected` interpreted as `internal` OR `protected` and not as `internal` AND `protected`?
2. Is there a way I can declare a constructor internal and protected?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Specifying internal is enough.

It's an abstract class - it's implied that its constructor is protected because you can't make an instance of it - you can do nothing BUT inherit it.

Comment: Actually, that's not true. From outside the assembly, the "protected" modifier still comes into play. If you declare an empty constructor as "internal" only, you can inherit the class outside the assembly, but you can't add a custom constructor to it. If you make it "protected internal", then you can.

Comment: @RobinHood70 I simply answered his specific query. In the the general case, you are correct.

Answer (score 4):

If you specify the constructor as **internal** it will be visible for all classes in your assembly and will not be visible to classes outside of it, which is exactly what you want to achieve. In short if a constructor or a class member of class A is:

- **Protected** - visible to all classes that inherit from A in its and in any other assembly
- **Internal** - visible to all classes in class A's assembly
- **Protected Internal** - visible to all classes that inherit from A in its and in any other assembly and to all classes in A's assembly

So in you case you only need to specify the constructor as internal.

Answer (score 0):

Did you try ?

Msdn tell us  that

> Constructors can be marked as public, private, protected, internal, or
>   protected internal.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173115%28v=vs.100%29.aspx

Comment: Yes I did try it and got confused, hence my question :)